# App Engine Python 3 development environment

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to upgrade my app engine app from python 2 to python 3. My app uses the app engine datastore (now cloud datastore). Google's docs are not at all clear about how to test this stuff locally. I've tried dev_appserver.py (which I've used for years with Python 2) but that's yielding the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 108, in <module>
    assert sys.version_info[0] == 2
AssertionError
```

I do have both Python 3 & Python 2 installed.

... I'm using Ubuntu for development in a Python virtual environment

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. `File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 108, in assert sys.version_info[0] == 2 AssertionError`

   The above error means you tried to start `dev_appserver.py` with a non-python2 executable. `dev_appserver.py` needs to be invoked with Python2 no matter the runtime or version in which your target App is written (i.e. even if your App is written in Python 3). As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/tools/local-devserver-command?tab=python) says

   > If Python 2 is not the default interpreter on your system, you need to run `python2 dev_appserver.py` to ensure the Python 2 interpreter is used

   **Summary:** Make sure `Python2` is your default Python executable in which case you can simply do `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`. If `Python2` isn't your default Python executable, then you have to use the command `python2 dev_appserver.py`
2. If you use the bundled APIs, then I don't believe you'll need the Cloud Datastore Emulator. You can run your App the same way you were doing it for Python 2. To enable bundled APIs for Python 3, see [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access)

Comment: After installing Python 2 I am able to invoke dev_appserver.py with python2 OR python3. It seems not to care. In order to run Python 3 apps I'm adding the "--runtime python310" parameter. Anyway, I'm moving forward now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment. If you're not abandoning your question, can you rephrase your comment?

Comment: It would appear that "dev_appserver.py needs to be invoked with Python2 no matter the runtime or version in which your target App is written" is not correct. I am able to invoke dev_appserver.py using either python2 or python3. I guess that that's my point.

Comment: Got it now. That's interesting. But when you invoked with Python3, do you still get the error ```assert sys.version_info[0] == 2 AssertionError```?

Comment: I rechecked the source for ```dev_appserver.py``` (I'm on a Mac, gcloud SDK 409.0.0) and the last line is the following ```if __name__ == '__main__': assert sys.version_info[0] == 2``` That line means - check the major version of the python executable which invoked dev_appserver.py and confirm it's '2'. Maybe things have changed on a latter version of gcloud SDK or maybe it's different for Ubuntu. You can check to see if this is what you have in your own version

Comment: It has changed. I'm using (well, trying to use) the latest version. It's a bit wonky but somewhat functional :)

Comment: hmm, let's step back a bit. Right now, what python version do you use to invoke dev_appserver.py? What error do you now get when you invoke dev_appserver.py using that python version?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that dev_appserver.py does now work with Python 3. Either invoke it directly with python3 or make sure that python3 is the default python interpreter.